# How PHP make compsition?

Tags: php

in c++ :

```
class first{
    int x;
    first ();
}

class tow{
    int y;
    first fst;
    tow ();
}

class three{
    int z;
    tow tw;
    three ();
}

void main(){
    three obj = new three;
    int var=obj . tw . fst . x; //how I can access to x from a obj ??
}
```

my question is : what the  syntax of PHP to access to data member like (x) from an instance from class like (three)???

Comment: You need to post the php code you have for your classes instead; the answer depends on how your properties are declared.

Comment: if you had the same classes and object names in php, it would be $obj->tw->fst->x

Comment: ok thank  you very much Andrew it work as you said

Comment: @Andrew - please post answer, I will remove mine.

Comment: @Nick You don't have to remove it. It looks fine. lemar you can accept Nick's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you are looking for:

```
<?

class first{
    public $x;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->x = 42;
    }

}

class tow{
    public $y;
    public $fst;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->fst = new first;
    }

}

class three{
    public $z;
    public $tw;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->tw = new tow;
    }
}

$obj = new three;
// assuming there is a constructors that fill eveyhing correct.
$var = $obj->tw->fst->x;

echo $var . "\n";
```

Here is working example.